# Create an index with url_datastore

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-text

I must create an index with the parameter URL_DATASTORE in oracle 11 but, when I try to create this index, oracle return me this error

```
create index IDX_IT on informazioni_testi(
indextype is ctxsys.context 
parameters ( 'Datastore CTXSYS.URL_DATASTORE' );

Error starting at line 1 in command:
create index IDX_IT on informazioni_testi(url) 
indextype is ctxsys.context 
parameters ( 'Datastore CTXSYS.FILE_DATASTORE' )
Error at Command Line:1 Column:13
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10758: index owner does not have the privilege to use file or URL datastore
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 160
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 366
29855. 00000 -  "error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine"
*Cause:    Failed to successfully execute the ODCIIndexCreate routine.
*Action:   Check to see if the routine has been coded correctly.
```

I think to have given all possible grant

```
grant RESOURCE TO parlamento2018; -->GRANT RESOURCE succeeded.
grant CONNECT TO parlamento2018; --> grant CONNECT succeeded.
grant CTXAPP TO parlamento2018; --> grant CTXAPP succeeded.
grant execute on ctx_ddl to parlamento2018; --> grant execute succeeded.
grant execute on CTX_CLS to parlamento2018; --> grant execute succeeded.
grant execute on CTX_DOC to parlamento2018; --> grant execute succeeded.
grant execute on CTX_OUTPUT to parlamento2018; --> grant execute succeeded.
grant execute on CTX_QUERY to parlamento2018; --> grant execute succeeded.
grant execute on CTX_REPORT to parlamento2018; --> grant execute succeeded.
grant execute on CTX_THES to parlamento2018; --> grant execute succeeded.
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect as SYS and run

```
exec ctxsys.ctx_adm.set_parameter('FILE_ACCESS_ROLE', 'KEIICHI')  ;
                                                       -------
                              username that is trying to create index
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already gave this command

    >sqlplus.exe / as sysdba

    SQL> exec ctxsys.ctx_adm.set_parameter('file_access_role', 'public')
    
    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.